# java oracle database change notification

Tags: amazon-ec2, oracle12c

I have one application deployed on Red Hat Linux and Oracle 12c.

As part of the application, there is an implementation of Oracle Database Change Notification. Whenever there is a change in the database, that triggers a notification back to the application server. Based on that, the application makes some decisions. Here everything is working well.

Now we are migrating application to amazon EC2 instance with our Red Hat Linux box converted into an EC2 instance and the Oracle Database migrated to cloud. I don’t know what that means, but I do have connection parameters and I'm able to connect though the JDBC driver from my application deployed in the EC2 instance.

Somehow the database change notification functionality is not working in EC2and nothing can be tracked from the application log.

Comment: It is all very abstractive, what do you have?

Comment: Post your security group config..

Comment: database on aws cloud..It must be RDS. (because it Oracle is relational database)

Answer (score 0):

`Oracle Database` in cloud in aws, which I consider it has to be `RDS`.

You need to understand the basic on how the application is deployed in `aws cloud`.

The `EC2(with app server) must be in public subnet` with security group allowing `http/https` traffic.

The `RDS` is kept in private subnet with security group attached which only allows incoming traffic from `EC2` instance ( or public subnet).This is general scenario in most of the cases.

The `RDS` security group only allows the incoming traffic from `ec2`. but any traffic from your DB (Outgoing traffic) has to be explicitly allowed from the security group attached to Your RDS.

The same traffic needs to be allowed in your `Ec2` instance security group.

I am unaware of your specific feature, whether it is supported in AWS RDS or not, you should take a look at [AWS RDS Oracle docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Oracle.html)